# How to reverse a bar chart in highcharts?

Tags: highcharts

Are there some highcharts pros out there?

What i want is, that value 6 (lowest score) starts left and on the right there is the highest score (1)

so the bars heading to 1 (showing the space to be mark 1)

like:

```
|------------------------(1.9)

|--------------------(2.3)

|----------------------------(1.4)

6..............3................1
```

http://jsfiddle.net/aCz2s/1/

Any help with that?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can set `reversed` to `yAxis` too, like you did on `xAxis`.

Like this:

```
xAxis: {
    reversed: true
},
yAxis: {
    reversed: true
}
```

Here is a [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/aCz2s/4/)

Comment: Changing the xAxis from true to false does not produce a different chart.

Comment: Looks like changing the xAxis reversed to false works.  I also found out that the default for bar chart's xAxis reversed is true, so don't expect it to change if you set it to true!

Comment: @MichaelBattaglia Actually the reversed x axis was changed recently, in 4.1.10. [Here is the issue](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/3737). And [here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lulylulu/aCz2s/117/) with 4.1.9 and without reversed x axis.

Comment: how can you make 1 have the longest bar? if 1 es the top value, its bar should be the bigger one.

Answer (score 2):

I would do something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/wergeld/aCz2s/5/).
What is important here and is kind of clunky. Is to make your values be negative and then use the label formatter on the xAxis to have them appear positive (with adjusted min/max):

```
    yAxis: {
        min: -6,
        max: 0,
        title: {
            text: 'Marks from  6 (very bad) to 1 (yery good)',
            align: 'high'
        },
        labels: {
            overflow: 'justify',
            formatter: function() {
            return this.value * -1;
        }
        }
    }
```

Also set the Xaxis to be on the opposite side:

```
    xAxis: {
        reversed:true,
        categories: ['John', 'Sandy', 'Carl', 'Maria'],
        title: {
            text: null
        },
        opposite: true
    }
```