# In Highcharts, how to reverse y-axis under "Bar" chart type?

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

I am trying to reverse the y-axis under 'Bar' type of chart, but seems it is not working as in other types of chart. After setting 'reversed' of y-axis to true, instead of reverting y-axis, the axis actually got reversed is x-axis. Is there any way to reverse y-axis?

Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/scottszb1987/2h5Lfx2t/

```
yAxis: [{
    reversed: true
}],
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13562452/how-to-reverse-a-bar-chart-in-highcharts

Comment: Sorry but that question didn't really help. That question is about reversing 'x-axis', but what I wanted is a reversed 'y-axis'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The bar chart is a column chart with inverted axis (switched x and y). Therefore you have to change the setting for the x-axis.

Also, for inverted axis, `reversed` is `true` by default, so you have to change it on the x-axis, and set it to `false`.

For example ([JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2h5Lfx2t/4/)):

```
xAxis: {
    reversed: false
}
```

Comment: Awesome answer! That's why setting xAxis.reversed to true didn't work. Thank you so much.